# Failed to import external libraries in IronPython

Tags: python, c#, ironpython

I want to run a Python application with IronPython.

This is the error:

```
Unhandled exception. IronPython.Runtime.Exceptions.ImportException: Cannot import name IntFlag
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Runtime.LightExceptions.ThrowException(LightException lightEx)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Runtime.LightExceptions.CheckAndThrow(Object value)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.FuncCallInstruction`2.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.Interpreter.HandleException(InterpretedFrame frame, Exception exception)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.Interpreter.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.LightLambda.Run2[T0,T1,TRet](T0 arg0, T1 arg1)
   at IronPython.Compiler.PythonScriptCode.RunWorker(CodeContext ctx)
   at IronPython.Compiler.PythonScriptCode.Run(Scope scope)
   at IronPython.Compiler.RuntimeScriptCode.InvokeTarget(Scope scope)
   at IronPython.Compiler.RuntimeScriptCode.Run(Scope scope)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.SourceUnit.Execute(Scope scope, ErrorSink errorSink)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.SourceUnit.Execute(Scope scope)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting.ScriptSource.Execute(ScriptScope scope)
```

I tried manually adding the libraries to IronPython.

I have already encountered a situation of a missing library which was present in *site-packages*. When I added it, the problem was solved.

The rest of the folders I have added to the paths contains *.py* files.

```
using System;
using IronPython.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting;

namespace IronPythonExample
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Set the Python script file path
            string pythonScriptPath = @"/usr/PhyProgram.py";
            // Execute the script
            // Create a new Python runtime
            ScriptEngine engine = Python.CreateEngine();
            var searchPaths = engine.GetSearchPaths();
            searchPaths.Add(@"/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages");
            searchPaths.Add(@"/usr/phy_core_lib");
            searchPaths.Add(@"/usr/phy_core_lib/src");
            searchPaths.Add(@"/usr/phy_core_lib/src/network");
            searchPaths.Add(@"/usr/phy_core_lib/src/network/prm");
            engine.SetSearchPaths(searchPaths);
            ScriptScope scope = engine.CreateScope();
            engine.CreateScriptSourceFromFile(pythonScriptPath).Execute(scope);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What IronPython version are you using and what is happening in your Python source code that triggers the error?

Comment: 3.4.1
I failed in the Scope line of the c# code
some files in the python app use IntFlag witch should contains in enum package

Answer (score 0):

The standard python library you seem to be referencing ([3.4.1](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.4.1/Lib/enum.py), the one shipped with the current IronPython release) does not contain IntFlag as it was introduced in [3.6](https://docs.python.org/3.6/whatsnew/changelog.html#python-3-6-0-beta-1). The current state can be seen [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/enum.py).

It is likely, that the code that you try to run is not (yet) compatible with the features offered by IronPython right now.

Comment: can you advise regarding another methods to run python application via c# ? I tried PythonNet but its also make issues